# Listening for 2 Pusher apps in same page using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, twilio, pusher

I have been using pusher for quite a few months with success. I won't go into the details of the "push" part of the solution because that works already. My issue is with the listener side when I try to listen to a second app. Please note that I said a second app not a second channel on the same app.

Here is what I have that has worked well for at least 6 months and continues to work well until I try to add a second version of this on the same HTML/PHP page in the HEAD section.

I have changed the keys an certain info for obvious reasons.

How can I add a second copy of this pointing to a second app within Pusher?

My concern is that I will have issues if there are things like identical variables such as channel. I have tried renaming the channel to channel 2 and pusher to pusher 2 but then it quits working..

```
<!-- Start Pusher Code -->
  <script src="https://d3dy5gmtp8yhk7.cloudfront.net/2.1/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var pusher = new Pusher('0000000000');
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('appname');

    channel.bind('channelname', function(data) {

    MyURL = 'http://www.google.com';

    newwindow=window.open(MyURL,data.cuid,'height=800,width=950,scrollbars=yes');

    });
  </script>
  <!-- End Pusher Code -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self-executing closure:

```
( function() {
  // some code
} )();
```

to ensure that the variables don't clash. Also, remember to declare variables using `var` or they leak to the global scope.

If possible, I would include the Pusher `<script>` tag just once.

```
<script src="https://d3dy5gmtp8yhk7.cloudfront.net/2.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
<!-- Start Pusher Code -->
<script>
( function() {
  var pusher = new Pusher('app_key_1');
  var channel = pusher.subscribe('appname');

  channel.bind('channelname', function(data) {

    var MyURL = 'http://www.google.com';

    var newwindow=window.open(MyURL,data.cuid,'height=800,width=950,scrollbars=yes');

  });
} )();
</script>
<!-- End Pusher Code -->

<!-- Start Pusher Code -->
<script>
( function() {
  var pusher = new Pusher('app_key_2');
  var channel = pusher.subscribe('appname');

  channel.bind('channelname', function(data) {

    var MyURL = 'http://www.google.com';

    var newwindow = window.open(MyURL,data.cuid,'height=800,width=950,scrollbars=yes');

  });
} )();
</script>
<!-- End Pusher Code -->
```

I've used two different application keys to confirm that you are connecting to two different applications.

Comment: OK, I will give that a shot. I was just concerned about the clashing as you mentioned. If the code you gave me will do the trick and not causing references to "data." to get mixed up etc, then that's what I am looking to accomplish. Although, I have to say that I am pretty curious why I can just rename the "pusher" and "channel" vars.. Somehow that breaks the code.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure leaving the variables the same in both instances would have actually been a problem but... My brain tells me it would have been. Thanks again!

Comment: The `data` variable only exists in the scope of the function it's passed to. It's very possible that the variables being overwritten wasn't causing a problem - it's just best not to do that. It may be that including the Pusher script tag twice was the cause. It could have been overwriting references. I'm not 100% sure, but pleased the above fixes things.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more.. I wasn't 100% sure it would have been broke if I re-used the variables. I just didn't want to and when I tried to change them, that broke things. I never really tried being sloppy about it and leaving the variables the same, that's why I wanted advice. Always learning :-) Thanks again!